# Generate Specific pattern using Strings and Matrix using java

Tags: java, string, matrix

I need to generate a specific pattern using String and Matrix in java. The user should be able to input any odd position character from A-Z. Example if user selects G, Then the output should be:

ABCDEFGFEDCBA 
ABCDEF   FEDCBA 
ABCDE          EDCBA  
ABCD                DCBA  
ABC                        CBA  
AB                               BA  
A                                      A

I tried the following code: But I am not getting the desired output:

```
    import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class PatternDemo3 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
    {        
        Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a odd positioned letter from A to Z to create the pattern : ");
        char input=(char)System.in.read();
        int val=(int)input;
        int newvalue=val-64;

        for (int i =newvalue; i >=0; i--) 
        {
            int begining=65;
            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) 
            {
                System.out.print((char)begining);
                begining++;                
            }
            int newbeg=begining-1;            
            for(int k=0;k<(2*i-1);k++)
            {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }            
            for (int j = 0; j <i; j++) 
            {
                System.out.print((char)newbeg);
                newbeg--;                              
            }
            System.out.println("");            
        }        
    }    
}
```

Comment: Show us what did you try. Some error? SO user will not do the work for you.

Comment: @BrunoCésar , I have made the changes. The error i am getting is the mismatch of spacing between the two set of loop.As well as last letter  in the first line is getting repeated, I want to remove the same. Thanks

Comment: You probably need `k < 2 * (newvalue - i)` in the "space loop", see http://ideone.com/XI5GAA. G is doubled on first line, you'll have to fix that.

Answer (score 2):

This is the final code after editing the response I received.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class PatternDemo3 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
    {        
        Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a odd positioned letter from A to Z to create the pattern : ");
        char input=(char)System.in.read();
        int val=(int)input;
        int newvalue=val-64;

        for (int i =newvalue; i >=0; i--) 
        {
            int begining=65;
            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) 
            {
                System.out.print((char)begining);
                begining++;                
            }
            int newbeg=begining-1;            
            for(int k=1; k< 2 * (newvalue-i);k++)
            {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }            
            for (int j = 0; j <i; j++) 
            {
                if((char)newbeg!=input)
                {
                System.out.print((char)newbeg);
                }
                newbeg--;

            }
            System.out.println("");            
        }        
    }    
}
```